# Popups- one after the other

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to show to user popups for 2 seconds, one after one (could be any number suppose 17).
any ideas how to do that?

```
function sleep(miliseconds) {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

  while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
  }
}

/*First option*/ 

function printFailureMessages (failureMessages){
  failureMessages.forEach(message => {
      document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML = message;
      document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
      sleep(1500);
      document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
  });
}

/*Second option*/

function printFailureMessages (failureMessages){
  failureMessages.forEach(message => {
      document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML = message;
      document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
      },1500);
  });
}
```

works well when failureMessages size is one...
BTW - i tried some more variations with setTimeOut , not successful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `async/await` for this like:

```
// Return a promise that resolves after "miliseconds" milliseconds
function sleep(miliseconds) {
   return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, miliseconds));
}

// Make this function async function
async function printFailureMessages(failureMessages) {
   for (var i = 0; i < failureMessages.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("myPopup").innerHTML = failureMessages[i];
      document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
      await sleep(1500); // wait for this promise to finish
      document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
   }
}

printFailureMessages(['Hello', 'World']);
```